# De-Selecting Shortcut Key (Blender 2.8)

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut

In Blender 2.8, the shortcut key to de-select all objects is to double tap the A key twice. Is there any way to change that to just one tap of the A key, like how it was in Blender 2.79?